# left most bit of a number mips

Tags: bit-manipulation, mips, bit-shift

```
# 1 - Request a number
# 2 - Read the number
# 3 - Display Binary msg
# 4 - Display the number as binary
# 5 - Find the left-most bit (loop)
# 6 - Display the result msg
# 7 - Display the position


.data 
    prompt:    .asciiz "Enter a 16 bit number: "
    binaryMsg: .asciiz "\nBinary: "
    results:   .asciiz "\nThe left most bit is in position(zero based): "
        .text
    .globl main
    
    main:
    
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, prompt
        syscall
        
        li $v0, 5
        syscall 
        move $a1, $v0
        
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, binaryMsg
        syscall
        
        
        
        
       jal prtbin
    
        # New Line
        li $v0, 11
        li $a0, 10
        syscall
    
       jal main
        
        prtbin:
        add $t0, $zero, $a1 # put our input ($a1) into $t0
        add $t1, $zero, $zero # Zero out $t1
        addi $t3, $zero, 1 # load 1 as a mask
        sll $t3, $t3, 15 # move the mask to appropriate position
        addi $t4, $zero, 16 # loop counter
        
        loop:
        and $t1, $t0, $t3 # and the input with the mask
        beq $t1, $zero, print # Branch to print if its 0
    
        add $t1, $zero, $zero # Zero out $t1
        addi $t1, $zero, 1 # Put a 1 in $t1
        j print
        
        
        print:
           
        li $v0, 1
        move $a0, $t1
        syscall
        
        srl $t3, $t3, 1
        addi $t4, $t4, -1
        bne $t4, $zero, loop
    
 
        
        
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, results
        syscall
        
        
        li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

I'm building a program that takes a 16 bit number converts it to binary and gets the left most bit and outputs that position of it. I'm having two issues one being I cant seem to get it work without looping back to the main and cant seem to get the left most bit and output that into the results. any help will be much appreciated.

update
I figured out how to get it from looping but now I still cant seem to find out how to get the left most bit and display that

Comment: Try to write some pseudo code, or better yet, C code so you can make an algorithm that does the job.  Without an algorithm, and also learning assembly.  Once you have an algorithm working in C, then translate each little construct faithfully into assembly, and it will work the same as the C.

Comment: figured it out! thanks

Comment: @JACKERHAIDAN great! Consider writing a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help others with the same problem as you.